# Word frequencies from large body of scraped text

Tags: python, performance, hash-map, lookup

I have a file with word frequency logs from a very messy corpus of scraped Polish text that I am trying to clean to get accurate word frequencies. Since this is a big text file, I divided it into batches.

Here is a snippet from the original file:

> ```
>  1 środka(byłe
>  1 środka.było
>  1 środkacccxli.
>  1 (środkach)
>  1 „środkach”
>  1 środ­kach
>  1 środkach...
>  1 środkach.",
>  1 środkach"
>  1 środkach".
>  1 środkachwzorem
>  1 środkach.życie
>  1 środkajak
>  1 "środkami"
>  1 (środkami)
>  1 „środkami”)
>  1 środkami!"
>  1 środkami”
>  1 środkami)?
>  1 środkami˝.
> ```

My goal is to clean true word labels and remove noisy word labels (e.g. collocations of words concatenated through punctuation). This is what is achieved by the first part of the script. As you can see in the data sample above, several noisy entries belong to the same true label. Once cleaned, their frequencies should be added. This is what I try to achieve in the second part of my script.

Here is the code in one piece with fixed indentation, in case you are able to reproduce my issues on your end:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

num_batches = 54

for i in range(1 ,num_batches +1):

    infile_path = r'input_batch_' + str(i) + r'.txt'
    outfile_path = r'output_batch_' + str(i) + r'.txt'

    with io.open(infile_path, 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as infile, \
         io.open(outfile_path, 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:

        entries_raw = infile.readlines()
        entries_single = [x.strip() for x in entries_raw]
        entries = [x.split('\t') for x in entries_single]

        data = pd.DataFrame({"word": [], "freq": []})

        for j in range(len(entries)):
            data.loc[j] = entries[j][1], entries[j][0]

            freq_dict = dict()
            keys = np.unique(data['word'])

            for key in keys:
                for x in range(len(data)):
                    if data['word'][x] == key:
                        if key in freq_dict:
                            prior_freq = freq_dict.get(key)
                            freq_dict[key] = prior_freq + data['freq'][x]
                        else:
                            freq_dict[key] = data['freq'][x]

        for key in freq_dict.keys():
        outfile.write("%s,%s\n" % (key, freq_dict[key]))
```

The problem with this code is that it is either buggy, running into an infinite loop or sth, or is very slow, even for processing a single batch, to the point of being impractical. Are there ways to streamline this code to make it computationally tractable? In particular, can I achieve the same goal without using `for` loops? Or by using a different data structure for word-frequency lookup than a dictionary?

Comment: I've added the fixed code in one piece below. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in range(1 ,num_batches +1):
```

Your inter-token spacing here is a little wonky. I suggest running this code through a linter to get it to be PEP8-compliant.

This string:

```
r'input_batch_' + str(i) + r'.txt'
```

can be:

```
f'input_batch_{i}.txt'
```

This code:

```
entries_raw = infile.readlines()
entries_single = [x.strip() for x in entries_raw]
entries = [x.split('\t') for x in entries_single]
```

can also be simplified, to:

```
entries = [line.rstrip().split('\t') for line in infile]
```

Note a few things. You don't need to call `readlines()`; you can treat the file object itself as an iterator. Also, avoid calling a variable `x` even if it's an intermediate variable; you need meaningful names.

This is an antipattern inherited from C:

```
for j in range(len(entries)):
    data.loc[j] = entries[j][1], entries[j][0]
```

You should instead do:

```
for j, entry in enumerate(entries):
    data.loc[j] = entry[1], entry[0]
```

That also applies to your `for x in range(len(data)):`.

This:

```
freq_dict = dict()
```

should be:

```
freq_dict = {}
```

This:

```
if key in freq_dict:
    prior_freq = freq_dict.get(key)
    freq_dict[key] = prior_freq + data['freq'][x]
else:
    freq_dict[key] = data['freq'][x]
```

can be simplified to:

```
prior_freq = freq_dict.get(key)
freq_dict[key] = data['freq'][x]
if prior_freq is not None:
    freq_dict[key] += prior_freq
```

or even (courtesy @AlexHall):

```
freq_dict[key] = data['freq'][x] + freq_dict.get(key, 0)
```

Note a few things. First of all, you were inappropriately using `get` - either check for key presence and then use `[]`, or use `get` and then check the return value (which is preferred, as it requires fewer key lookups).

This loop:

```
for key in freq_dict.keys():
outfile.write("%s,%s\n" % (key, freq_dict[key]))
```

needs adjustment in a few ways. Firstly, it won't run at all because its indentation is wrong. Also, rather that only iterating over `keys`, you should be iterating over `items`:

```
for key, freq in freq_dict.items():
    outfile.write(f'{key},{freq}\n')
```

Comment: The `freq_dict` code is wrong because it calls `.get` after assigning to that key. In any case it can be simplified more to `freq_dict[key] = data['freq'][x] + freq_dict.get(key, 0)`.

Comment: @AlexHall Good eyes. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

Reinderien covered most of the other issues with your code. But you should know there's a built-in class for simplifying the task of tallying word frequencies:

```
from collections import Counter

yourListOfWords = [...]

frequencyOfEachWord = Counter(yourListOfWords)
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [the answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/210196/98493) by [@AleksandrH](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/126348/aleksandrh), this is how I would write it using `collections.Counter`:

```
import io
from collections import Counter
import regex as re  # the normal re module does not support \p{P}...

def read_file(file_name):
    """Reads a file into a Counter object.

    File contains rows with counts and words.
    Words can be multiple words separated by punctuation or whitespace.
    If that is the case, separate them.
    """
    counter = Counter()
    with io.open(file_name, 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if not line:
                continue
            freq, words = line.strip().split('\t')  # need to omit '\t' when testing, because SO replaces tabs with whitespace
            # split on punctuation and whitespace
            words = re.split(r'\p{P}|\s', words)
            # update all words
            for word in filter(None, words):  # filter out empty strings
                counter[word] += int(freq)
    return counter

def write_file(file_name, counter):
    with io.open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(f'{word},{freq}\n' for word, freq in counter.most_common())  # use `items` if order does not matter


if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_batches = 54
    for i in range(1, num_batches + 1):
        counter = read_file(f"input_batch_{i}.txt")
        write_file(f"output_batch_{i}.txt", counter)
```

This also has (the start of) a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) describing what the `read_file` function does, functions in the first place in order to separate concerns, and a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from this script without the main code running.